# How to diagnose regular focus losses

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

I'm having some strange effects on my computer which I am having trouble diagnosing.

1) When in Netflix (or other web-based video app) in full screen mode, full screen is exited every 50 minutes (approximate)

2) When running a full screen program (such as a video game), I get sent to desktop periodically.  This occurs independent of game, but I haven't actually timed the frequency.  The game isn't must minimized showing the next window down, but rather all the way down to the desktop.

I think there's some process which is periodically "stealing" focus, but this is a total guess and I have no way of confirming.

Some things to note:

- Running Windows 7 64-bit
- Virus scan comes up clean
- I recently upgrade graphics cards, but this did not begin until after (Radeon 5770 to ATI R9 270X)

What steps can I take to diagnose the problem so that I can move towards an eventual solution?

**Update:**

Reverting to the old card seemed to stop the issue.  I will re-install the new card and update the drivers and see if that fixes the issue, if not, it must be the actual card hardware, right?

Comment: Recently upgraded the graphics card... To what, from what? How big is your power supply? Does your old card still work?

Comment: ATI Radeon 5550 to ATI R9 270X.  Had to upgrade the power supply along with the new card, which happened a week or so later, so I definitely have sufficient power.  The old card should still work

Comment: Check the new video card manufacture's website for reported issues or updated drivers. If no luck there, reinstall the previous card (remove new card drivers) and see if the problem still exists. If not, it might be a defective card or compatibility issue. If it's still an issue, look at what processes are running in the background.

Comment: Disable anything (everything) that runs on start up that isn't critical to the operation of your computer. If you can't disable it, exit after the process loads or kill it. Have you tried this? You indicate that you suspect it might be a problem.

Comment: @CharlieRB, see the update

Comment: After reading your update, I suggest contacting the video card manufacturer's support for assistance.

Comment: @CharlieRB, ok, since this question was how to diagnose the issue, if you want to write up your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the new video card manufacture's website for reported issues or updated drivers.

If no luck there, reinstall the previous card (remove new card drivers) and see if the problem still exists. If not, it might be a defective card or compatibility issue. If it's still an issue, look at what processes are running in the background.